# I am trying to set a ImageView on onActivityResult by picking image with Camera or Gallery intent

Tags: android, imageview, onactivityresult

On onActivity result, I would like to set the image for ProfileImageView.I am starting the intent and trying to set the image in onActivity Result. Is this a correct way to do this

```
public class EditProfile extends AppCompatActivity  {

TextView tv;
EditText et;
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
String edititemname="";
Toolbar toolbar;
private ArrayList<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();

private int REQUEST_CODE_PICKER = 2000;
ImageView profileImage,image1,image2,image3,image4;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_profile);
    initData();
    profileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (currentapiVersion > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                getPermission();
            }
            final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
                    "Cancel"};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    EditProfile.this);
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                        Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);

                    } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {

                        Intent photoPic = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(photoPic,1);
                    } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();

        }
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
            switch (requestCode) {
                case 0:
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                        profileImage.setImageURI(selectedImage);
                    }

                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                        profileImage.setImageURI(selectedImage);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }





});

}




private void initData() {

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_back));
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i=new Intent(EditProfile.this,ProfileView.class);
            startActivity(i);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.no_anim);
    }
    });
    profileImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.prof_image);
    image1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image1);
    image2=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image2);
    image3=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image3);
    image4=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image4);


}




@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private void getPermission() {
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

        String[] permissions_dummy = new String[2];
        int i = 0;

        String permission = "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE";
        int res = checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
        if (res != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            permissions_dummy[i] = permission;
            i = i + 1;


        }
        permission="android.permission.CAMERA";
        res = checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
        if (res != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            permissions_dummy[i] = permission;
            i = i + 1;


        }


        String[] permissions = new String[i];

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

            permissions[j] = permissions_dummy[j];

        }


        int yourRequestId = 1;
        if (i != 0) {


            // Do something for lollipop and above versions
            requestPermissions(permissions, yourRequestId);
            Log.d("shan","Area 1 Executing");


        }

    }

}
```

}

Can Anyone guide me, wher I am making a mistake

Edit 2 :

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent         imageReturnedIntent) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);
switch (requestCode) {
    case 0:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            profileImage.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }

        break;
    case 1:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            profileImage.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            image1.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }

        break;
    case 3:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            image1.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }
        break;
    case 4:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            image2.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }

        break;
    case 5:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            image2.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }
        break;
    case 6:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            image3.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }

        break;
    case 7:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            image3.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }
        break;
    case 8:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            image4.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }

        break;
    case 9:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            image4.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }
        break;
}
```

}

```
 private  void picselect(int capture, int gallery) {
 final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Library",
        "Cancel"};

 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        EditProfile.this);
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    int c=capture;
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
            Intent takePicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(takePicture,capture);

        } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {

            Intent photoPic = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(photoPic,gallery);
        } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
});
builder.show();
```

}

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.prof_image:{
        if (currentapiVersion > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getPermission();
        }
        picselect(0,1);
    }
    case R.id.image1:{
        if (currentapiVersion > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getPermission();
        }
        picselect(2,3);
    }
    case R.id.image2:{
        if (currentapiVersion > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getPermission();
        }
        picselect(4,5);
    }
    case R.id.image3:{
        if (currentapiVersion > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getPermission();
        }
        picselect(6,7);
    }
    case R.id.image4:{
        if (currentapiVersion > android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getPermission();
        }
        picselect(8,9);
    }
  }

}
```

But I'm getting issue in accessing capture and gallery integer variables inside @overided onclick function. Without using final variable, how can I make this done

Comment: Whats wrong? You are not able to set the image you pick?

Comment: super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent)

Comment: and what's wrong on your code?

Comment: it is telling that it cannot resolve, this onActivityResult

Comment: what mistake am I making over there?

Comment: @ShanPLT where do you have that code in Activity/ Fragment or elsewhere?

Comment: @ShanPLT please post full file so we can help u

Comment: @sush I have added full code

Comment: like profileImage, I want to set the onClickListeners for other imageViews image1, image2 , image3 and image4 to get the image from Camera or gallery Intent . And thats why I have written code like this. Please someone guide me to complete this assignment

Comment: Why do you extend AppCompatActivity? Try to extend Activity.

Comment: won't it affect lower model mobiles?

Comment: and I am using a toolbar too

Comment: I think it doesn't effect.

Comment: If I extend Activity, I am unable to use toolbar overe there

Comment: @ShanPLT you got to move your onActivityResult. It must be under activity scope. Copy and paste the entire method code just before the end of last curly brace

Comment: First, is it possible to define a onActivityResult Function like this, inside a annonymous inner class

Comment: @Ragu   last curly brace?

Comment: Could you be more specific

Comment: @ShanPLT check my answer. You need to move your onActivityResult and make it a overridden method of your Activity class.